# Windows batch file programing multiline user input load into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need some help with Windows batch programming. I made a bat script, I need to insert user-input text into a variable. When I insert one line of text it works, but when I copy & paste a paragraph, it only gets one line. All I need is prompt user to input a paragraph and then show it back to the user.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P cname=Please copy and paste paragraph: 
IF "%cname%"=="" GOTO Error
echo %cname%
Pause
```

Comment: In batch files the variables aren't suited for containing paragraphs with line breaks.  If you explain what it is you need to do then there may be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nl=^


set nl=^^^%nl%%nl%^%nl%%nl%
:loop
set line=
set /p line=Please copy and paste paragraph: 
if not defined line goto break
set p=%p%!nl!%line%
goto loop
:break
echo %p%
```

try that